# @pandas_udf gives me SyntaxError

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

@pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP) gives me  SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing in Azure databricks because of @ sign.
Is there any pyspark udf alternative to pandas_udf?
Is @ supposed to be replaced with anything else?

I am trying to run this code:

```
@pandas_udf(result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP) ####ERROR
def forecast_store_item(history_pd):
    # instantiate the model, configure the parameters
    model = Prophet(
        interval_width=0.95,
        growth='linear',
        daily_seasonality=False,
        weekly_seasonality=True,
        yearly_seasonality=True,
        seasonality_mode='multiplicative'
    )

    # fit the model
    model.fit(history_pd)

    # configure predictions
    future_pd = model.make_future_dataframe(
        periods=90,
        freq='d',
        include_history=True
    )

    # make predictions
    results_pd = model.predict(future_pd)

    # . . .

    # return predictions
    return results_pd
```

The reason I need grouped_map is that I need to parallely run fbprophet model training for multiple store, item combinations like done below.

```
results = (
    store_item_history
    .groupBy('store', 'item')
    .apply(forecast_store_item)
    .withColumn('training_date', current_date())
    )
```

The code mentioned in this question is taken from here:
https://databricks.com/blog/2020/01/27/time-series-forecasting-prophet-spark.html

I believe the syntax error is due to '@'.

Comment: please show the complete error traceback. it's probably not related to the @ but some other errors somewhere

Comment: which line causes the error?

Comment: @pandas_udf(schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP), if I remove @ it doesnt give me an error, but it doesnt solve the purpose

Comment: maybe try removing that line and after the function definition, put `forecast_store_item = pandas_udf(forecast_store_item, result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)`

Comment: close to reopening your question.